# retrieving from database rawquery android not working

Tags: android, database, data-retrieval

I am having 2 values, imsi and phone num. I store them in database.i get problem in retriving database in getSIMContacts functn.addContact adds phonenum to database. getSIMContacts retrieves phonenum from database. my code looks like this->

```
public class PersonalContactsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PersonalContacts";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String IMEI_MOB = "imei";
    private static final String KEY_MO_NO = "mobile_no";

    Contact contact;

    public PersonalContactsDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    // Creating Tables
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," 
                + KEY_MO_NO + " TEXT,"
                + IMEI_MOB + " TEXT" 
                + ")";

        System.out.println("Create Query :::::"+CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

        Log.e("DB Manager", "Db created Succesfully "+db);
        //Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(String contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(IMEI_MOB, contact.getImei()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_MO_NO, contact); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public List<String> getSIMContacts() {
        List<String> contactList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_MO_NO +" FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                /*Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setStrId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                //contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setMobileNum(cursor.getString(2));*/
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

Iread the post and edited the data.
Imade the changes but when I am retrieving data, I get into infinite loop. code is as follows

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  List<String> list;
                  list=db.getSIMContacts();
                  while(list.iterator().hasNext())
                  {
                      String retrieved_num=list.iterator().next();
                      listItems.add(retrieved_num); 
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                  }

              }
      });
```

on this databasae, I want KEY_ID to be primary key with auto increment and decremant function and there is another function used to get the mobile num corresponding to the key id value.it looks like this but has some problems. Please help me resolve it

```
String getContact(int id) {
    String str="";
        try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID
                  }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

         str+=cursor.getString(2);
        // return contact
        cursor.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Get Contact Exception", ""+e);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong , as you have given field `KEY_MO_NO` in quotes.

this

```
  String selectQuery = "SELECT " + "KEY_MO_NO" +" FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
```

should be

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_MO_NO +" FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
```